# SQL DATABASE SYSTEMS QUERY PROBLEM for Student database Universal Quantification

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, subquery

Relations:
Student - contains a sNumber and sName

| sNumber | sName |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Dave |
| 20 | Sam |
| 30 | Amy |
| 40 | Ron |
| 50 | Ava |

Courses - contains the cNumber and cDescription

| cNumber | cDescription |
| --- | --- |
| MATH100 | Algebra 1 |
| SCI200 | Biology |
| ENG300 | Writing 1 |

Enrollments - sNumber, cNumber, and final grade

| sNumber | cNumber | final |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | MATH100 | 90 |
| 10 | SCI200 | 85 |
| 20 | ENG300 | 100 |
| 30 | MATH100 | 99 |
| 30 | SCI200 | 92 |
| 30 | ENG300 | 91 |
| 50 | ENG300 | 84 |

Universal Quantification Query: Find the student name and student number for the student(s) who have enrolled in ALL of the courses Dave has enrolled in. Dont include Dave in your answer.

The answer should be Amy and her sNumber.

My solution is not correct, Any help ???

[image: my solution]

Here is the solution i attempted in text form :
SELECT stud.sName, stud.sNumber
FROM Student stud
WHERE s.sName != 'Dave'
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT True
FROM Enrollment enroll
WHERE enroll.sNumber = stud.sNumber
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT True
FROM Courses course
WHERE course.cNumber = enroll.cNumber AND stud.sName = 'Dave'));

Comment: Post picture like a text please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551